# ") expect on line 7" Error in c program when passing structure's data

Tags: c, function, arguments, structure

## Help me i'm getting ") expected on line" 7 and line 8 error in a C program

Code:

```
typedef struct {
    int rollnum;
    char name[20];
    char pass[20];
}student;

void updateName(student s1.name); //Getting error here
void updatePass(student s1.pass); // and here
// and all other functions like these

int main()
{
    //Some code here....
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: . is not a valid character in an identifier...

Comment: how about `void updateName(student s1);` remember that variable name can't have period in it,

Comment: but i want to a single same function and the type of argument sets the particular task of updating  a particular value like if i'm passing s1.name it should only update name  and when i'm passing rollnum it should touch only roll number

Answer (score 1):

Your function parameters are wrong, basically wrong syntax. They should be

```
void updateName(char *name); 
void updatePass(char *pass);
```

You probably want to also pass the pointer to the updated student structure, so you'll declare *two* parameters, e.g.

```
void updateName(student*stud, char*name);
```

Comment: but what if i have a same function and i want to pass different arguments and the operation depends on type of the argument is like if i'm passing s1.name i only want to update name and when i'm passing s1.rollnum i only want to update rollnum.

Comment: does c supports method overloading?

Comment: No. C doesn't support any kind of overloading operations.

Comment: @Basile, Oh! You fixed a major flaw. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

rollnum,name,pass all are different arguments for the function, function copies whatever arguments you pass in its scope, and then executes

so  you can solve this problem using pointer to your variables as function arguments(See FUNCTION CALL BY REFERANCE) 
Or Just pass a single variable in one arguments